# Indicador de votos

Tags: android

Quero fazer um simples aplicativo para android de contagem de votos.  Só que em vez de aparecer números, quero que mostre uma barra que a medida que a votação aumenta, ela sobe, mudando de cor, como aparece no "Quem chega lá?" do Faustão, ou aquele do concurso de bandas "SuperStar". Alguém poderia me dizer que linha de pesquisa devo fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem o que você quer, uma simples barra de progresso que você pode setar o progresso e cor, você pode usar essa biblioteca: [Link](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar)

É simples de usar e você pode mudar tudo dinamicamente, cor, máximo, ícone, caso você queira.